# Need to Update data in 2 different tables, one is wordpress table and another is normal Table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have a website running using a database table. Now, I have added a wordpress site that has been created in subdomain. Now my requirement is to update both the tables.
When the user signup or signin using my main domain website, which is not wordpress. The wordpress table also should get updated with the username and password that is being used in the Main domain site.

So when the user sign in both the main domain and wordpress table(subdomain) also should get updated.

Comment: show your effort please.? what you did ?

Comment: We do not have idea how to combine both the tables.

Comment: that's ok you don't understand...but you can use internet search engines like google to find an [answer](https://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=sql%20send%20data%20two%20tables&oq=sql%20send%20data%20two%20tables&aqs=chrome..69i57.7227j0j7). Select the first result, or the 2nd, 3rd, 4th whatever. After you have tried and failed, post what you have tried and we'll guide you

Comment: I tried searching and did not get proper answer for this particular solution. thats why i have posted it over here.